# Extract an array out of a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array in php as follows.

```
MyArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => c
            [val] => 290
        )

   [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => a
            [val] => 160
        )

   [3] => Array
        (
           [id] => v
           [val] => 150
        )
)
```

out of this array i want to extract `array(c,a,v)`
I am not able to extract this particular array out of the above multidimensional array.
How can i achieve it?

Comment: Their keys differ. What is the relationship? Is it always the first element of the sub-array, no matter its key? Please always be as specific as possible with your requirements. Otherwise, answerers are left to guess at your real need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) might help.

```
array_map(function($elem) { return array_values($elem)[0]; }, $array);
```

Comment: The value `'v'` does not come from a key `['id']`

Comment: Hi sorry i just updated my array name. Can you tell me which variable i should replace it with in your code? and in variable the  array is returned into?

Comment: `$array` stays for the name of array (the latter variable.)

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you to use `array_map()`.

```
$your_arr = array(
    array(
        "id" => "c" ,"val" => 290 ),
    array(
        "id" => "a","val" => 160,
    ),
    array(
        "user" => "v","val" => 150,
    )
);

$arr = array_map(function($v){
    return $v['id']; 
}, $your_arr);

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => a
    [2] => v
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP >= 5.5 you can use array_column()

```
$letters = array_column($originalArray, 'id');
```